# PHP form posting blank data in to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a form in order to post data in to a mysql database but when I submit the form it just enters blank data. I'm fairly new to PHP and mysql so if you can help using the simplest explanation, not assuming any great in depth knowledge that would be really appreciated.

```
    <?php
DEFINE('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
 DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
 DEFINE('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
 DEFINE('DB_DATABASE', 'users');

 $con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

if(!$con) {

    echo 'not connected to server';
}

if (!mysqli_select_db($con, 'users'))
{
    echo 'no database selected';
}

$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$band = $_POST["band"];

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (Names, Emails, BandName) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$band')";

if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql))

    {

    echo 'Not worked';

    } else {

    echo 'worked';

    }

?>
```

Comment: something to do with your *unshown* HTML form.

Comment: you also don't need `if (!mysqli_select_db($con, 'users'))` you already declared it.

Comment: Are you sure your `<form>` element is configured to send variables via POST, and not the default of GET?

Comment: Not to mention this code is vulnerable to SQL injections. You should learn about SQL escaping, and better, prepared statements.

Comment: if you're echoing out 'worked' than be sure that the problem lies in you html.

Comment: and you're left without a puppy. I overstayed my 5 mins. here. Good luck with that.

Comment: this is my form code 

<form action="index.php" method="POST" id="form">

 <label for="name">Name:</label>
 <input id="name" type="text">
 </br>
 <label for="email">Email:</label>
 <input id="email" type="text">
 </br>
 <label for="band">Band Name:</label>
 <input id="band" type="text">
 </br>
 <input id="submit" type="submit">

 </form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php code like this better

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if (mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
    echo 'worked';
  } else {
    echo 'Not worked';
  }
}
?>
```

Html form must be like this :

```
<form action="" method="POST">

  <input type="text" name="name"/>
  <input type="text" name="email"/>
  <input type="text" name="band"/>

  <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```